# why is the outcome of evaluating these two php expressions different?

Tags: php, expression

```
$bBoolVal = ((6 < 5) Or (13 - 6 > 0));
if ($bBoolVal)  echo 'makes sense'; else echo 'makes no sense';
```

outcome: "makes sense"

```
$bBoolVal = (6 < 5) Or (13 - 6 > 0);
if ($bBoolVal)  echo 'makes sense'; else echo 'makes no sense';
```

outcome: "makes no sense"

It is as if '=' binds tighter than 'Or' - surely not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the = has higher precedence. A familiar example of exploiting this mechanism is frequently seen in the php manual:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

it works like

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I use your example construct all the time, but never made the connection!

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is correct as per the operator precedence in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

The `'&&', '||'` has greater precedence than `'='`, but the `'='` has greater precedence than '`and', 'or'`

Answer (score 0):

> It is as if '=' binds tighter than 'Or' - surely not?

It does.

It starts with OR and evaluates the right side first: the return value of the assignment is false. The value of the whole expression is true but you only check for what was assigned to `$bBoolVal`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Use `||` instead of `or` to make it bind tighter than the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in other form:

```
$bBoolVal = ((false) Or (true)); //true
if ($bBoolVal)  echo 'makes sense'; 
else echo 'makes no sense';



$bBoolVal = (false) Or (true); //false
(($bBoolVal  = false) or true) //equivalent expression which is false

if ($bBoolVal)  echo 'makes sense'; 
else echo 'makes no sense';
```